# Vimeo add wildcard domain to whitelist

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

Is it possible to use wildcard domains e.g. *.example.com in the service
"Add a domain to a video's whitelist"
We have
test.example.com
live.example.com
do I need to add both or can I use a wildcard?

regards
Meex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wildcards are not allowed, you'll need to whitelist each subdomain individually, see the Vimeo Help Center article here: https://vimeo.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/224819527-Changing-the-privacy-settings-of-your-videos

> subdomains will need to be added individually; adding the main domain will not cover subdomains. Wildcard characters are not supported.